# Spring H2 created table not found after successful creation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, h2

I am using Spring Boot's `schema.sql` magic to create an in memory H2 database. The script contains the following statements:

```
create table PERSON
(
    ID BIGINT not null primary key,
    NAME VARCHAR(255) not null
);

create index IDX_PERSON_NAME on PERSON (NAME);
```

Upon launch Spring Boo fails with the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of URL [file:/D:/git/.../build/resources/main/schema.sql]: create index IDX_PERSON_NAME on PERSON (NAME); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "PERSON" not found; SQL statement:
create index IDX_PERSON_NAME on PERSON (NAME) [42102-200]
```

How can the statement fail to find the table that was created in the preceding statement?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the possible reasons,

1. The schema needs to be mentioned on while referring to table like `test_schema.person`
2. Your syntax for creating the index might be wrong. Refer to this link for H2 Syntax,https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml

Answer (score 0):

Simply because `NAME` is not mentioned as `Unique` constraint, you have only specified it as `NOT NULL` constraint

```
create table PERSON
(
    ID BIGINT not null primary key,
    NAME VARCHAR(255) not null,
    CONSTRAINT Person_Name_Unique UNIQUE (NAME)

);


create index IDX_PERSON_NAME on PERSON (NAME);
```